# Calling another module from mainloop() of GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I am trying to create a chat server where multiple clients can connect to a server. I want to create a GUI in one module (say `clientgui.py`) which calls another module (say `client.py`) to connect to the server.

The problem is I have to call `client.py` when a certain button is clicked. But while doing so, the main loop never gets executed. For example,

```
app = Tk()

...

sendbutton = Button(text,height...., command = Client().senddata())
#This will call function of a different module.

....

app.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to call another module inside a "GUI loop"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the function to `command`, but the result of `senddata`. Try this instead:

```
sendbutton = Button(text, height, ..., command = Client().senddata)
```

That should solve your problem. Notice how the `senddata` method has no parenthesis on it? That is because you don't want to call it right there, you want to *talk* about it. Since functions and methods are objects, it is ok to assign it to a parameter (e.g. `command`).

What your code was doing, was assign the result of calling `Client().senddata()` to the buttons command. I assume this doesn't return a function/method/callable object (but it could) and that instead you assign `None`, in effect making the button not do anything at all when clicked.

Comment: @rocklearnpython, you're welcome. glad to have been of assistance.